# VSCode removes python imports automatically but unnecessarily on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, python-3.10, autosave

VSCode removes python imports automatically but unnecessarily on save. How do I know which extension(s) is/are playing foul here?

Comment: not the default behavior. disable all extensions and try again, also have a look at your `settings.json` (global and workspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pylance playing foul here! https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3144